# Merging Two Datasets Using Different Column names: left_Join

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, tidyverse

I am trying to merge two datasets using two separate column names, but that share same unique values. For instance, column A in dataset 1== xyzw, while in dataset 2, the column's name is B but the value == xyzw.

However, the problem is that in dataset 2, column's B value == xyzw refers to firm names and appears several times, depending on how many employees are in that firm that exist in the dataset.

Essentially, I want to create a new column, let's call it C in dataset 1 telling me how many employees are in each firm.

I have tried the following:

```
## Counting how many teachers are in each matched school, using the "Matched" column from matching_file_V4, along with the school_name column from the sample11 dataset:
merged_dataset <- left_join(sample11,matched_datasets,by="school_name")
```

While this code works, it is not really providing me with the number of employees per firm.

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide a sample data and expected output, It'd makes it easier for others to help. But that notwithstanding, I hope this gives you what you want:

Assuming we have these two data frames:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  A = letters[1:5],
  B = c('empl_1','empl_2','empl_3','empl_4','empl_5')
)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  C = sample(rep(c('empl_1','empl_2','empl_3','empl_4','empl_5'), 15), 50),
  D = sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace=T)
)


# I suggest you find the number of employees for each firm in the second data frame  


df_2%>%group_by(C)%>%
  summarise(
    num_empl = n()
  )%>%  ### Then do the left join
  left_join(
    df_1,., by=c('B' = 'C') ## this is how you can join on two different column names
  )

#   A      B num_empl
# 1 a empl_1        8
# 2 b empl_2       11
# 3 c empl_3       10
# 4 d empl_4       10
# 5 e empl_5       11
```